# iOS background fetch, where and when to schedule

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-fetch

I want to use background updates for one of my apps, and little bit confused about the logic of background fetch - where and when I have to call `setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:` method? Tutorials on the web are advising to call it on `application:
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, but what happens when application is launched manually by user before the scheduled background fetch is not yet started? Does it get cancelled and re-scheduled, or one more fetch operation is scheduled for the app? Please, advise! Thanks in advance for the comments and answers!